# Unable to run script in testng

Tags: java, testng, appium

I am not able to execute the whole script. Right now my script runs for `@BeforeTest` annotation, not running for `@Test` and `@AfterTest`.

```
public class LaunchApp {

  WebDriver driver = null;

  @BeforeTest
    public void setup() throws InterruptedException{

      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
      capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.4.13.1");
      capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
      capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.2");
      capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "CC55EYG01397");
      capabilities.setCapability("app", "E:\\build_1026.apk");
      try {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
            new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

  @Test
    public void appiumExampleTest() throws Exception {

      WebElement phNo = driver.findElement(By.id("editTextFirst"));
      phNo.sendKeys("99999999");

      driver.findElement(By.id("textViewContinue"));


    }

  @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
      if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit();
      }
    }
}
```

Even when I run from `testng.xml` the script is still not running fully.
Let me know where I am mistaken.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it clearer for users to understand it and thus help you. Good luck!

Comment: How do you know the test is not run? Notice `@AfterTest` method won't be run if the test doesn't run or fails. Be careful, TestNG is not JUnit and `@Before/AfterTest` is not `@BeforeAfterMethod`.

Comment: I have executed the above script in junit by using Before, Test, After annotations. It is executed completely. But in testng facing issue. I think my annotation is incorrect.

Comment: As was mentioned, try using '@BeforeMethod' and '@AfterMethod'.  You may also want to try: '@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)' and '@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)'

Comment: Are you using TestNG annotations instead of JUnit ones? Event if TestNG is supposed to work with JUnit annotations, you should not use it.

Comment: Thanks Juherr, it was my silly mistake. :D  I have used junit annotation for testng script. Now it is running successfully . :)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are using the @Test annotation from the TestNG library. There are chances @Test annotation may be pointing to the JUnit library. Just check it, That may fix it.